# get image from a website through web view objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimage

I'm doing an application in which I open a site through an UIWebView. 
I want the user to "download" of an image so that it can be crafted and edited in the application.

eg open a UIWebView on google images and pick one image.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you tap and hold on an image, say in google images, a user will be prompted to save the image to their library. Maybe you should do that, and then ask for access to the users photo library?